# Pivot Table in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, dynamic-sql

Hi i have a dynamic table looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID_Question` varchar(2), `ID_Solution` varchar(4), `ID_Mapping` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID_Question`, `ID_Solution`, `ID_Mapping`)
VALUES
    ('B1', 'GFC1', 1),
    ('B1', 'GFC2', 0),
    ('B1', 'GFC3', 0),
    ('B1', 'AFC1', 1),
    ('B1', 'AFC2', 0),
    ('B2', 'GFC1', 0),
    ('B2', 'GFC2', 1),
    ('B2', 'GFC3', 0),
    ('B2', 'AFC1', 0),
    ('B2', 'AFC2', 1),
    ('B2', 'GFC1', 0),
    ('B2', 'GFC2', 1),
    ('B2', 'GFC3', 0),
    ('B2', 'AFC1', 0),
    ('B2', 'AFC2', 1)
;
```

Basically it would look like this,

```
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| ID_Question | ID_Solution | ID_Mapping |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
| B1          | GFC1        |          1 |
| B1          | GFC2        |          0 |
| B1          | GFC3        |          0 |
| B1          | AFC1        |          1 |
| B1          | AFC2        |          0 |
| B2          | GFC1        |          0 |
| B2          | GFC2        |          1 |
| B2          | GFC3        |          0 |
| B2          | AFC1        |          0 |
| B2          | AFC2        |          1 |
| B2          | GFC1        |          0 |
| B2          | GFC2        |          1 |
| B2          | GFC3        |          0 |
| B2          | AFC1        |          0 |
| B2          | AFC2        |          1 |
+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

I wonder if i can show dynamicaly (where data can be add and removed) to be like:

```
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ID_SOLUSI | GFC1 | GFC2 | GFC3 | ASF1 | AFC2 |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| B1        | 1    | 0    | 0    | 1    | 1    |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| B2        | 0    | 1    | 0    | 1    | 0    |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| B3        | 1    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 1    |
+-----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I've try using this but it seems not working:

```
    SET @sql_ = (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT("ID_mapping AS " , ID_Solution))
        FROM table1
    );
SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT ID_QUESTION, ', 
              @sql_dinamis , ' 
           FROM tabl1
           GROUP BY ID_QUESTION
           WITH ROLLUP'
       );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

It would be great if you could also explain the concept to me since i kinda suck at SQL Query (Amazing right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind dynamic SQL, which you are trying to use here, is that to use a query to generate another query, that you can then execute.

It may help to visualize first the query that you are trying to build dynamically. For your sample data, that would be:

```
select 
    id_question, 
    max(case when id_solution = 'AFC1' then id_mapping end) as `AFC1`, 
    max(case when id_solution = 'AFC2' then id_mapping end) as `AFC2`, 
    max(case when id_solution = 'GFC1' then id_mapping end) as `GFC1`, 
    max(case when id_solution = 'GFC2' then id_mapping end) as `GFC2`, 
    max(case when id_solution = 'GFC3' then id_mapping end) as `GFC3` 
from Table1 
group by id_question with rollup
```

Here is the code for that purpose:

```
-- generate the `max()` expressions in the `from` clause
set @sql = (
    select group_concat(
        distinct 'max(case when id_solution = ''', id_solution, ''' then id_mapping end) as `', id_solution, '`'
        order by id_solution
        separator ', '
    ) from Table1
);

-- debug
select @sql;

-- now build the rest of the query string
set @sql = concat('select id_question, ', @sql, ' from Table1 group by id_question with rollup');

-- debug
select @sql;

-- finally, run the query for good
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3233e97bab96f0e855c86656cb145c7)**

Comment: Amazing... and i was so close too... thank you so much